# Set selected <select> option using jQuery based on value not text

Tags: jquery, select

I am working on some HTML/JavaScript code.

I have the following  box.

```
<select style="height: 90px;" id="cboApplications" name="cboApplications[]" multiple>
   <option value="1">App 1</option>
   <option value="2">App 2</option>
   <option value="3">App 3</option>
</select>
```

I have the following JavaScript code

```
$("#cboApplications option[value=2]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

For some reason though, nothing gets selected, and no errors are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. You need to enclose 2 with quotes, it will fix your issue.

```js
$("#cboApplications option[value='2']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="height: 90px;" id="cboApplications" name="cboApplications[]" multiple>
   <option value="1">App 1</option>
   <option value="2">App 2</option>
   <option value="3">App 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but for some reason this hasn't worked. Still doesn't get selected and no errors

Comment: Thanks this has worked after all, as I mentioned in another answer, I was calling the functions in the wrong order to populate and select

Comment: @Boardy, I would still recommend you to use either `.val()` or `.prop()` Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr Now Its up to you to decide whether to use best practice  or not

Comment: I found when I used the val it would only set 1 item and I need to be select multiple items

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) to set the value.

> A string of text, a number, or an array of strings corresponding to the value of each matched element to set as selected/checked.

```
$("#cboApplications").val(2);
```

*OR*

```
$("#cboApplications option[value=2]").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: Thanks but neither of these have worked for me for some reason

Comment: @Boardy, See it works http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/bygp5kve/ Can you share more information? Are you using AJAX or some other framework?

Comment: D'oh, I was calling a couple of functions in the wrong order, I was selecting it, then populating it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use this: 
    `$("#cboApplications").val(2);`

Comment: Providing some explanation in your answer will help your readers to learn.